# Need to Hide one List Element

Tags: css

I'm customizing only CSS on an underlying platform (so I cannot edit HTML). I need to hide one item in a list that looks like this:

```
<li><a href="#" data-part="menu-link" data-page="earn"><span class="icon icon-star"></span>Earn points</a></li>
```

How can I achieve this with CSS without blocking the entire list?

Comment: How many items do you have in your list? And will its position change?

Comment: Is there anything unique that can identify the link?

Comment: the data-page="earn" is unique to this item in the list. There are items that fall below this list item, but I am assuming they will bump up once it's hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the list item position, and it is fixed within the parent list (it's always 1st, or 2nd, etc...), you can use [`nth-child`](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=nth-child&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=syKhVoOQMIP-wQT7_J6ACQ). So, if the item is third in the list, you can do:

```
ul li:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

However, you still need to qualify the parent `ul`; otherwise, this will affect all list elements on the page.

If this is not the case, you might have to use JavaScript. And if `data-page="earn"` is unique to the contained, element, you can do something like this if You have jQuery. Otherwise you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
$('a[data-page="earn"]').parent('li').remove();
```